# How to remove the purple "duplicated code fragment" highlighting in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I just clicked "*Show all duplicates like this*" in the "*Duplicated code fragment*" context menu:

[image: Duplicated code fragment]

Now the duplicated code is permanently highlighted with a purple background, even if I close the "Duplicates" toolbar at the bottom of the IDE.

**How do I remove this highlighting?**

Answer (score 215, accepted):

- Simply hit the `ESC` key to remove that highlighting.
- If the IDE is finding "Duplicate code fragments" between your source code and a copy of it in an output directory (like Python `setup.py` creates in a `build/` directory; I don't know how this goes in PHP), then mark the output directory as *excluded* from source directories.

  Right-click the output directory in the Project View, then `Mark Directory As` > `Excluded`.

BTW, this works in PyCharm and IntelliJ as well, and presumably in all the JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: This is the correct answer for IntelliJ with PHP. In my case the highlighting was green, although I don't know if that is the default color or due to some style change I made.

Comment: I think it uses green highlighting in dark mode

Comment: It feels like this should be far more intuitive! For some reason didn't even think to try ESC :)

Comment: Works in Intellij with java too.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I lost my mind by staring the purple highlight while having no clue how to get rid of it.

Comment: the solution is really simple but many people here googled it. (including me, cheers:)

Comment: ESC key also works for PyCharm. Thank you

Comment: How would one know that it's "simply" ESC. Stackoverflow is simple, Intellij is not.

Comment: @Arny, heh. Yes, it's simple to do it this way; not obvious to discover.

Comment: FFS this has driven me crazy for like 3+ years and I finally decided to figure out how to fix it—I feel like an idiot now realizing it was such a simple trick...

Comment: Spent hours in PyCharm to figure it out and finally decided to google it, found this answer lol... so simple `ESC`. I think JetBrains should add an info box or a better way to undo this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Just re-open the file/project - it will remove the highlighting.
If you don't like the "Duplicate code fragment" violation to be reported for your code fragment, try suppressing inspection for statement by adding `// noinspection DuplicatedCode` before it.

There is a request for making the duplicates highlighting less aggressive, [IDEA-210614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210614), please feel fre to vote for it

Comment: Thanks, restarting PHPStorm does make it disappear. I'm surprised that there isn't another way, though?

Comment: Indeed there is a quicker way.

Comment: Which is to simply press `esc` as suggested in the top answer.

Comment: should add `/** @noinspection DuplicatedCode */` `at the top of the file